# Unable to use JCA CICS resource with IBM WebSphere Application Server Liberty Profile

Tags: websphere-liberty

I'm trying to setup WLP for an existing EAR application.
This setup works fine with WAS 9 traditional.

The problem is the JCA CICS Resource Adapter call.

The server.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server description="new server">

    <!-- Enable features -->
    <featureManager>
        <feature>javaee-7.0</feature>
    </featureManager>

    <!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
    <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
                  host="*"
                  httpPort="9080"
                  httpsPort="9443" />

    <!-- Automatically expand WAR files and EAR files -->
    <applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>

    <library id="sharedLibs">
        <fileset dir="/work/sharedlibs" includes="*.jar"/>
        <folder dir="/work" />
    </library>

    <resourceAdapter
            autoStart="true"
            id="eciResourceAdapter"
            location="/work/cicseci.rar">
    </resourceAdapter>

    <connectionFactory id="CTGDV06" jndiName="jca/CTGDV06" >
        <properties.eciResourceAdapter.javax.resource.cci.ConnectionFactory
                connectionUrl="tcp://*******"
                serverName="*******"
                userName="*******"
                portNumber="2006"
         />
    </connectionFactory>

    <application type="ear" id="app" location="app.ear" name="app">
        <classloader
                commonLibraryRef="sharedLibs"
                classProviderRef="eciResourceAdapter" />
    </application>
</server>
```

in ibm-web-bnd.xml :

```
<resource-ref name="cicsjca" binding-name="jca/CTGDV06"></resource-ref>
```

in web.xml :

```
<resource-ref id="ResourceRef_Cics_Jca">
    <description>Acces CICS</description>
    <res-ref-name>cicsjca</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.resource.cci.ConnectionFactory</res-type>
    <res-auth>Application</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

Startup is Ok, but access to JCA fail with :

```
java.lang.Exception: Lookup for java:comp/env/cicsjca failed. Exception: javax.naming.NamingException: CWNEN1001E: The object referenced by the java:comp/env/cicsjca JNDI name could not be instantiated. If the reference name maps to a JNDI name in the deployment descriptor bindings for the application performing the JNDI lookup, make sure that the JNDI name mapping in the deployment descriptor binding is correct. If the JNDI name mapping is correct, make sure the target resource can be resolved with the specified name relative to the default initial context. 
[Root exception is com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionException: CWNEN0030E: The server was unable to obtain an object instance for the java:comp/env/cicsjca reference.  The exception message was: CWNEN1003E: The server was unable to find the jca/CTGDV06 binding with the javax.resource.cci.ConnectionFactory type for the java:comp/env/cicsjca reference.]
```

I don't understand what's wrong with this setup, any help would be apreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct configuration depends on how many connection factory implementations are provided by the resource adapter.

If the resource adapter provides only a single connection factory (which is commonly the case for many resource adapters), then configuration would be:

```
<connectionFactory id="CTGDV06" jndiName="jca/CTGDV06" >
    <properties.eciResourceAdapter
            connectionUrl="tcp://*******"
            serverName="*******"
            userName="*******"
            portNumber="2006"
     />
</connectionFactory>
```

Full detail on how to specify configuration for JCA resource adapters in Liberty can be found [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_jca_config_confact.html) in the knowledge center.

Comment: I had tried this syntax earlier with no success. Now with your syntax I faced this exception : `java.lang.Exception: Lookup for java:comp/env/cicsjca failed. Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.connector2.cics.ECIConnectionFactory incompatible with com.ibm.connector2.cics.ECIConnectionFactory`

Comment: That exception indicates the same class is being loaded from 2 different locations.  Do you have a copy of that class in your RAR and in one of your sharedLib jars?  I suspect you only need to specify `classProviderRef` on your application classloader.

Comment: Exactly, cicseci.jar and other deps. are also loaded in the shared lib. The application use some proprietary frameworks that use this same jar. I check this ...

Comment: Moving the jars from the sharedLib to the EAR solved the problem. CICS call is now working. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @EmericChardiny, I'm trying the same and even the steps followed similar to yours, but I'm getting javax.naming.NamingNotFoundException. everything seems to be correct. Can you help me?